# Hibernate - howto filter on @ManyToOne (@OneToMany works...)

Tags: java, hibernate, filter

I'm using Hibernate 3.6.

When I use a `@OneToMany` relation with `@Filter`, it works.

Ex:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="item", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@Filter(name="filter_detail_status")
public List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<Detail>();
```

But when I use with the `@ManyToOne`, it doesn't.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="item_id")
@Filter(name="filter_item_status")
public Item item;
```

I check the SQL and the filter is not included.

I tried the `@Where` annotation on `@ManyToOne` and it doesn't work either.

How to filter on a `@ManyToOne`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I never used filter, but I use Criteria API to create more complex queries like those involved with many-to-one mappings.

Comment: Tks. What I need is just a filter on status. In my case, putting a criteria will be to verbose and it will make it more difficult to maintain (onetoMany -> filter, ManytoOne -> Criteria...)